# How to load data when input is empty?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an HTML table with multiple account numbers.

[image]

If I enter in the input the account number `979545130406`, the filter loads perfectly

[image]

My problem is that if I clear the value of the input (`979545130406`)

[image]

Nothing happens???? I would like to display all the recordings, is it possible to do that?

I share my code with you, thank you for your help.

**template**

```
<form #formulaire="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class=" row mb-4 align-items-end ">
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 ">
      <div class="mb-2 ">
         <!-- Portefeuille -->
         <h5>Portefeuille</h5>
         <input type="input" class="form-control form-max-width" name="account" [(ngModel)]="account" placeholder="Enter account number" (input)="onInputChange()">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**composent**

```
export class OverviewTransfersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private unsubscribe$ = new Subject < void > ();

   currentAgency: any;
   transferResponse: TransferResponse;
   account: string;

   constructor(
      private service: OverviewTransfersService,
      private store: Store,
      private modalService: BsModalService,
      private router: Router


   ) {
      this.account = '';
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.currentAgency = this.store.selectSnapshot(AgencyState.currentAgency);
      if (this.currentAgency) {
         this.OverviewTransfers(this.account);
      }
   }

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.unsubscribe$.next();
      this.unsubscribe$.complete();
   }

   OverviewTransfers(account: string): void {
      this.service.OverviewTransfers(account).pipe(
         takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      ).subscribe(res => {
         if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
            this.transferResponse = res as TransferResponse;
            console.log("data => ", this.transferResponse)
         }
      });
   }

   onSubmit(): void {
      console.log("account:", this.account);
      if (typeof this.account === 'string' && this.account.trim() !== '') {
         this.OverviewTransfers(this.account.trim());
      } else {
         alert("The wallet number field is mandatory");
      }
   }

   onInputChange(): void {
      if (typeof this.account === 'string' && this.account.trim() !== '') {
         this.OverviewTransfers(this.account.trim());
      }
   }

}
```

**EDIT**

**Service**

```
overviewTransfers(account: string): Observable < ApiResponse > {
  return this.http.post < ApiResponse > (this.api + `/AGHRAF`, {
     DEPO: account,  
     AGENCE: this.store.selectSnapshot(AgencyState.currentAgency).CODE
  });
```

Comment: Well your code clearly and explicitly only does anything when the input is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want `OverviewTransfersService.OverviewTransfers` to return all records on an empty string. You haven't showed the code for that, but that's where I would put that logic.

**In Overview Transfers Service**

```js
overviewTransfers(account: string) {
  if (!string) return // request for all accounts
  return // request for specific account
}
```

Then the component gets a lot simpler. If you initialize `account` to a string in the property declaration, there's no need to perform checks on it.

**Component**

```js
export class OverviewTransfersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private unsubscribe$ = new Subject < void > ();

   currentAgency: any;
   transferResponse: TransferResponse;
   account: string = '';

   constructor(
      private service: OverviewTransfersService,
      private store: Store,
      private modalService: BsModalService,
      private router: Router
   ) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.currentAgency = this.store.selectSnapshot(AgencyState.currentAgency);
      if (this.currentAgency) {
         this.overviewTransfers();
      }
   }

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.unsubscribe$.next();
      this.unsubscribe$.complete();
   }

   overviewTransfers(account: string): void {
      this.service.overviewTransfers(this.account.trim()).pipe(
         takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      ).subscribe(res => {
         if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
            this.transferResponse = res as TransferResponse;
            console.log("data => ", this.transferResponse)
         }
      });
   }

   onSubmit(): void {
      console.log("account:", this.account);
      this.overviewTransfers();
   }

   onInputChange(): void {
      this.overviewTransfers();
   }
}
```

I've changed the function names to camelCase because I thought it was a bit confusing having them capitalized.